# How to write a single SQL query to get aggregate of column as other column in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cumulative-sum

I have a table `Employee`.

[image]

How to get the table with aggregate of a column as separate column as shown in the image?

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried but not getting how to proceed.

Comment: Which dbms product are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact problem I faced last year. Hope this help.

```
SELECT e1.EmpId,
       e1.EmpName
       e1.EmpSalary,
       SUM(e2.EmpSalary) AS Aggregate_Salary 
FROM Employee e1 JOIN Employee e2 
ON e1.id >= e2.id GROUP BY e1.EmpId,
   e1.EmpName,
   e1.EmpSalary
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a correlated sub-query:

```
select EmpId, EmpName, EmpSalary, (select sum(EmpSalary) from Employee e2
                                   where e2.EmpId <= e1.EmpId) as AggregateSalary
from Employee e1
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select empid, 
       empname,
       empsalary,
       sum(empsalary) over (order by empid) as aggregate_salary
from employee
order by empid;
```